# Get path to temp folder (...\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\...) in post build event

Tags: c#, asp.net, batch-file

I wrote batch file that copy ClearScript dlls (ClearScriptV8-32.dll, ClearScriptV8-64.dll, v8-ia32.dll, v8-x64.dll) from packages folder to temp folder (...\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root...) that contains ClearScript.DLL.

And in Visual Studio I want in post-build events execute my batch file with parameters source and destination. Source - packages folder with ClearScript dlls, destination - temp folder ...\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root... with ClearScript.dll.

How can I do this?

Comment: In _Build Events_ tab where you write your post-build code there is also an _Edit post-build_ button where you visually can pick available macros that can be used as parameters.

Comment: what you mean by temp folder? its "...\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root" mean - one level up > temporary asp.net files > root.  or its the one inside the windows directory?